# Setting an environment variable in /etc/environment doesn't work but export does?

Tags: environment-variables, nodejs

So I'm trying to set an environment variable called "NODE_PATH",
It works by using:

```
export NODE_PATH=/home/myname/node
```

So I thought I'd set it up permanently and found that it needs to be done in the /etc/environment file.

After doing that and rebooting the machine, I ran:

```
echo $NODE_PATH
```

And the output is correct, yet node.js doesn't seem to like it.
But then, if I set it again using export, everything works fine.

I'd love to receive any input about the matter, is there a different functionality between the two that I'm not aware of?

Comment: I'm not aware of any difference. Either it is an environment variable, or it isn't. Sure you didn't make a mistake when testing?

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson I'm starting my node application and it does not work until I run the export line - if it matters, I'm under the root user.

Comment: The fact that you are root may certainly matter. How do you get root privileges? Via the `sudo` command?

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson Nope, that's the only user that exists and I'm logging into it via ssh

Comment: Then it shouldn't matter that you are root. Another way to set a system wide environment variable persistently is to put the `export` command into a `/etc/profile.d/*.sh` file. Should give the same result, but possibly worth trying.

Answer (score 0):

Close the console you're using then open it again, worked for me.